# How read of Object.keys() value JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

How read of Object.keys() value JSON ?

I trying read value key **name**, but give error:

**Keys dynamic**

```
             {
             "marka1": {
                 "name": "Mika",
               },
             "beti1": {
                 "name": "Yii",
                      }
               }
```

---

```
    var ojson = JSON.parse(objectJson);
    var keys = Object.keys(ojson); //read good key
    console.log("test  - " + ojson.keys[0].name); //give error
```

Comment: `JSON.parse(obj)` throws an error...

Comment: not clear what you are working with `var obj` is not JSON it is an object that doesn't need parsing as it is shown now. Report what actual error is

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks. I edited my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change it to `console.log("test  - " + ojson[ keys[0] ].name);` because `keys[0]` is just a string.

Comment: Good Very Thanks you)